# What is a reasonable widget count in a GTK3 application?

Tags: performance, gtk3

We have a Python GTK application with a large number of widgets 3-4k.

When porting from GTK2 to GTK3 we noticed a rather big performance hit when:

1. Adding widgets.
2. Simply showing (not creating) windows.

My question is: Is this a bug, or is it simply unreasonable to use many thousands of widgets in a GTK3 application?

The following test program `perf.py` shows both problems:

```python
import sys
import gi
import time
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk


class DialogExample(Gtk.Dialog):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Gtk.Dialog.__init__(self, "My Dialog", parent, 0,
            (Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
             Gtk.STOCK_OK, Gtk.ResponseType.OK))

        label = Gtk.Label("The snappiness of this dialog depends on the number of \nwidgets in the main program.")
        self.get_content_area().add(label)
        self.show_all()


class DialogWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self, count):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Dialog Example")

        box = Gtk.Box()
        self.add(box)

        button = Gtk.Button("Open dialog")
        button.connect("clicked", self.on_button_clicked)
        box.pack_start(button, expand=False, fill=True, padding=0)

        # Add dummy widgets to show effect
        for n in xrange(count):
            button = Gtk.Button(str(n))
            button.set_no_show_all(True)
            t = time.time()
            box.pack_start(button, expand=False, fill=True, padding=0)
            print('{}\t{:.3f}'.format(n, 1000*(time.time()-t)))

    def on_button_clicked(self, widget):
        dialog = DialogExample(self)
        dialog.run()
        dialog.destroy()


count = int(sys.argv[1])
win = DialogWindow(count)
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

1. The time to add a widget increases for each widget.
2. The time it takes to display a dialog is affected by the total widget count in the application.

The Python script takes a command line parameter which is the number of (hidden) widgets to create and prints the existing widget count and the time to add it.

```
$ python perf.py 20000
0       0.026
1       0.021
...
20000   1.700
```

At 20000 widgets, point 1 is pretty clear even on fast hardware. Point 2 might require slower hardware or double the widget count to be clearly visible.

The image below displays the widget creation time that goes from around 20 microseconds to 6 ms.
[image: Widget creation time (ms) vs number of widgets]
Number one is only somewhat unexpected, but the second point was totally unexpected to me.

I have tested this in Gtk 3.18 on three different machines.

Part of the main application window:
[image: Main application]

Comment: Are you really using 20000 widgets in one file? In the project I author, https://sourceforge.net/projects/pygtk-posting/  I use lots of widgets spread across several different files and I see no lag time to worry about.

Comment: @theGtknerd I am using in the region of 3-4 k widgets. On a regular laptop or desktop system it takes about 3 seconds to start, but on slower hardware (Atom) it takes about 30 seconds to load the application, and most of the time is spent in GTK. Approx. how many widgets is your app using?

Comment: I just opened 45 windows with >50 widgets per window not counting all the renderers in the treeview. There was some lag time but not like your example. Are your 3-4 K widgets all in the same file/window?

Comment: All widgets exist in a single window. The time to create the UI (30s) is annoying but possible to live with because it is mostly an always-on application. The lag of 0.5-1 s on the target hardware is more disturbing as it manifests itself every time a dialog or other window shall be displayed.

Comment: I played with it some more. I do get some lag time now with the same windows (> 50 widgets) and 50 windows. It seems dialogs are affected a bit more than other widgets, not positive on that though. And it does seem to *sometimes* affect other instances of Gtk 3 running at the same time. Is there no other way to accomplish your goal (without 3-4K widgets) ?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I understand that the UI sounds insane, but it is built up by widgets that contains a lot of small pieces that are mostly hidden and only displayed on demand. I'll attach a picture so you get the idea. Surely there must be another way, but I just wanted to know if this was a bug or expected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129830/discussion-between-thegtknerd-and-bohrax).